# Configuring Emacs/AucTeX in Windows 10 to use Sumatra PDF?

Tags: windows, auctex, sumatrapdf

This is surely easy-ish to do, but all the advice I can find is either several years old (2012), or not helpful - the [Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AUCTeX#toc26) claims that "Unfortunately, configuration can be tricky to get right, mainly because there are so many steps."  Well, I don't mind taking "many" steps, if I only knew which ones to take!  Note that I've used Emacs/AucTeX under Linux for years, but for reasons of work I'm having to spend more time in Windows 10.

Anyway, if I could be pointed to a fairly recent set of instructions or examples (of `.emacs` configurations, for example), I'd be very pleased.  Thanks!

Comment: I *think* the relevant variable is `TeX-view-program-list`. You might start there, via `describe-variable`

Answer (score 6):

AUCTeX's built-in support for SumatraPDF was improved with the
release of version 11.90.  So make sure you have the latest
version installed, which can be easily done from ELPA.

You need to touch three areas:

### Win10's PATH environment variable

This step is optional: Adjust the `PATH` environment variable and
add the directory containing `SumatraPDF.exe` to it.

### Emacs and AUCTeX

You have to adjust two AUCTeX variables: `TeX-view-program-list`
and `TeX-view-program-selection`.  In short, in
`TeX-view-program-list` you define the available viewers and in
`TeX-view-program-selection`, you associate the defined viewers
to the document types.  If you have `SumatraPDF` in your `PATH`,
you can skip this step.  Otherwise, you have to hardcode the path to
the executable in `TeX-view-program-list` by putting something
like this in your `.emacs`:

```el
(setq TeX-view-program-list
      '(("SumatraPDF"
         ("c:/path/to/SumatraPDF -reuse-instance"
          (mode-io-correlate " -forward-search \"%b\" %n")
          " %o")
         "SumatraPDF")))
```

Now you associate `SumatraPDF` as viewer for generated `.pdf`
files in `TeX-view-program-selection`.  Again, put this line in
your `.emacs`:

```el
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "SumatraPDF")))
```

Finally, make sure you have this line in your `.emacs`:

```el
(server-start)
```

Now restart Emacs.

### SumatraPDF

Configuring SumatraPDF is easy.  You need to add this line to
SumatraPDF preferences for inverse search:

```
"C:\path\to\emacs\bin\emacsclientw.exe" -n +%l "%f"
```

If you don't see the field for inverse search, open the file
`SumatraPDF-settings.txt`, search for `EnableTeXEnhancements` and
set it to `true`.  Restart SumatraPDF and try again.

### Compiling your .tex file

Open a `.tex` file, hit <kbd>C-c C-t C-s</kbd> and check the
message in the Minibuffer.  Make sure it says
`Tex-Source-Correlate mode enabled`.  Now hit <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>
to compile the file and <kbd>C-c C-v</kbd> to change to SumatraPDF.

Comment: Nice answer You are correct to NOT use the old commands -inverse-search It slows down usage but you can also remove -reuse-instance since that should have been set to ReuseInstance = true in SumatraPDF-settings.txt (just need to check via SumatraPDF Settings> Advanced options where you can also check that the InverseSearchCmdLine = your line above. A useful optional setting is HighlightPermanent = true as that persists the pdf highlight until the next call (permanent does NOT mean it is for ever :-)

Comment: @KJO - Thanks, my understanding of the question was "Configure AUCTeX and SumatraPDF".  Maybe you start a new question with "What is the best setting for SumatraPDF" and collect your hints there?

Comment: I have given similar answers to many questions re other editors as many popular answers still rely on old advice e.g. use DDE which is now a bad solution for lack of utf8 support etc.. Your answer is good for Auctex and with dozens of editors a "generic" question would likely invite lots of poor responses MyNotes can get out of date very quickly https://github.com/GitHubRulesOK/MyNotes/raw/master/AppNotes/SumatraPDF/LATeX%20and%20Reverse-Search.pdf and I need to possibly update again in line with your answer

Answer (score 0):

Just a small comment: if the path to SumatraPDF contains spaces (as is the case for a default install to "Program Files (x86)", then the path must be quoted: `"\"c:/Program Files (x86)/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF\" -reuse-instance"` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Another comment, be sure to launch emacs with
`emacsclientw.exe -n -c -a ""` to be able to connect to your running instance.
This is explained in detail here:
https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35545/setting-up-emacsclient-on-ms-windows